# Artoolkit v6. Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2. Crash on intel processors using x86 architecture (Asus zenfone 2 ZE551ML)

Tags: android, x86, x86-64, intel, artoolkit

ARToolkit v6.0 crashes on my phone (Asus Zenfone 2 ZE551ML) where the previous v5 used to work fine. I am guessing the issue is related to my phone's architecture that uses Intel chips (x86). I have tried on other phones with different architecture (arm architectures) and it works fine. Here is the log cat:

```
08-15 21:43:19.905 12158-12494/com.nishad.a4liodemo E/libAR: [error] ARController::androidVideoPush1: ARVideoSource is not running.
08-15 21:43:19.969 12158-12495/com.nishad.a4liodemo E/libAR: [error] ARController::androidVideoPush1: ARVideoSource is not running.
08-15 21:43:20.089 12158-12158/com.nishad.a4liodemo I/CaptureCameraPreview: surfaceChanged(): called
08-15 21:43:20.282 12158-12478/com.nishad.a4liodemo E/libAR: [error] Error performing CURL operation: Error (6). Could not resolve host: calibration.artoolkit.org.
08-15 21:43:20.282 12158-12478/com.nishad.a4liodemo E/libAR: [error] Error -4 returned from cparamSearch.
08-15 21:43:20.293 12158-12478/com.nishad.a4liodemo W/libAR: [warning] Using default camera parameters for 640x360 image size, 45 degrees vertical field-of-view.
08-15 21:43:21.193 12158-12452/com.nishad.a4liodemo E/org.artoolkit.ar6.base.rendering.ARRenderer: Proceed with simple shader program as we didn't get one from derived class
08-15 21:43:21.215 12158-12501/com.nishad.a4liodemo I/libAR: [info] Loading 2D image tracker data.
08-15 21:43:21.217 12158-12158/com.nishad.a4liodemo I/CaptureCameraPreview: onPreviewFrame(): Camera capture FPS: 3.8510911
08-15 21:43:21.222 12158-12501/com.nishad.a4liodemo I/libAR: [info] 'Data/qrcode.jpg' assigned page no. 0.
08-15 21:43:21.223 12158-12452/com.nishad.a4liodemo E/libAR: [error] ARView 0 not inited.
                 ------Beginning of Crash -------

08-15 21:43:21.227 12158-12501/com.nishad.a4liodemo A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xd8384b34 in tid 12501 (Thread-1890)
08-15 21:43:21.248 12158-12452/com.nishad.a4liodemo I/org.artoolkit.ar6.base.rendering.ARRenderer: Viewport {0, 0, 1920, 1080}.
08-15 21:43:21.286 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG: pid: 12158, tid: 12501, name: Thread-1890  >>> com.nishad.a4liodemo <<<
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00280b34  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN9artvision10DoGPyramidC1Ev+4)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0027f790  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN9artvision32DoGScaleInvariantFeatureDetectorINS_18BinomialPyramid32fEfEC2Effjjjf+80)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0027ece8  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN9artvision19FreakVisualDatabaseC1Ev+88)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 002689c2  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN9artvision27MultiTargetPlanarRecogniser4ImplC2ERKNSt6__ndk16vectorINS_6TargetENS2_9allocatorIS4_EEEE+914)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 002685c0  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN9artvision27MultiTargetPlanarRecogniserC1ERKNSt6__ndk16vectorINS_6TargetENS1_9allocatorIS3_EEEE+48)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000d0ee3  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN11ARTracker2D17load2DTrackerDataERNSt6__ndk16vectorIP11ARTrackableNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEjj+339)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000d0c30  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN11ARTracker2D6updateEP15AR2VideoBufferTS1_RNSt6__ndk16vectorIP11ARTrackableNS2_9allocatorIS5_EEEE+80)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000ca6d9  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (_ZN12ARController6updateEv+1145)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000c87a2  /data/app/com.nishad.a4liodemo-1/lib/x86/libAR6.so (Java_org_artoolkit_ar6_base_NativeInterface_arwUpdateAR+34)
08-15 21:43:21.311 24273-24273/? I/DEBUG:     #09 pc 01079786  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.nishad.a4liodemo-1@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately I don't have a x86 Android device to test with.